# Angular 4 Filteration on Button Click

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular 4 currently there is a list of data without filtration and on the left side, I have given category list. So, when any user will click on any of Category the list should be filtered. Please let me know how can I do this?

**xyz.component.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let category of categories; let i=index;" (click)="filter(0,category.id)">{{ category.name }}</li>
<div  *ngFor="let post of originalPosts; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="!post.blogger.team_link">
      {{post.blogger.name}}
 </div>
</div>
```

**xyz.component.ts**

```
  export class BlogComponent implements OnInit {
        filteredPosts=[];
        originalPosts=[];

        constructor(private blogService: BlogService) { 
          this.blogService.getBlogPosts().then(res=>this.originalPosts=res);
        }
        public filter(bgr, cat){
          if(cat != null){
            let category = this.categories[cat]
            this.filteredPosts = this.originalPosts.filter(d => d.category.id == cat);
          }
        }
    }
```

Current Output which displays all category
[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLTTR.png)

Expected Output which should display only the selected category eg. Author
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY5VE.png)

Unable To Filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
<li *ngFor="let category of categories; let i=index;" (click)="filter(category.id)">{{ category.name }}</li>
```

**component**

```
originalPosts = []; // add all posts
filteredPosts = [];

public filter(categoryId){  
    this.filteredPosts = this.originalPosts.filter(post => post.category.id === categoryId;
}
```

Comment: i need more help on this topic @Pratap

Comment: @Amit please ask another question and provide the link if it is different I am happy to help

Comment: i have edited the question and applied the solution which you have provided there is some issue in filtering in short unable to filter data remains same @Pratap

Comment: @Amit please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: i have edited the question current output and expected output @pratap

Comment: @Amit please find working stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akyp7e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Now it is working @ Pratap A.K . Can you please update the link code by giving two filter option and filtering the records on that two filter values.

Comment: @Amit inside filter function add OR condition it will work

Comment: how will i pass the another filter id in click event in html file @Pratap A.K